# Nightmare.js with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nightmare

I'm attempting to run Nightmare.js on the server. I'm well aware that it's headless on Linux, and requires `xvfb`. What I don't understand is why I continue to get the following error when in DEBUG mode:

```
  nightmare queuing process start +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "useragent" +3ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for https://news.ycombinator.com +2ms
  nightmare queueing action "cookies" +1ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for https://news.ycombinator.com/login +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "type" +1ms
  nightmare queueing action "type" +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "wait" +1ms
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11878025 +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "wait" +1ms
  nightmare running +0ms
  nightmare electron child process exited with code 2: undefined +25ms
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
    xvfb \
    x11-xkb-utils \
    xfonts-100dpi \
    xfonts-75dpi \
    xfonts-scalable \
    xfonts-cyrillic \
    x11-apps \
    clang \
    libdbus-1-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libnotify-dev \
    libgnome-keyring-dev \
    libgconf2-dev \
    libasound2-dev \
    libcap-dev \
    libcups2-dev \
    libxtst-dev \
    libxss1 \
    libnss3-dev \
    gcc-multilib \
    g++-multilib

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD DEBUG=nightmare* xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" node tux.js -s hn -m create -p 11878025
```

Any thoughts? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Nightmare are you using?

Comment: Could you run it with DEBUG=nightmare:*,electron:* and see if you get some useful log messages?

Comment: Running the latest version of nightmare.js (2.5.1), I get the following output in my post above.

Comment: Could you run your source with `DEBUG=*` and post the results?  In later versions of Electron, I think it _tries_ to be helpful and tell you what's missing.  (I've tried your Dockerfile with a simple example and cannot reproduce.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to put all your files in a subdirectory, say app/ and in your Dockerfile do:

```
ADD app/ /usr/src/app/
```

of course in your app folder there will be env.sh, package.json, tux.js and the lib directory

That way if you need to add more files, you wont have to add them manually in your dockerfile.

PS: It works with COPY too

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured out what the issue was. Apparently, it didn't like the copy syntax in my Dockerfile. I ended up using ADD and it worked.

```
ADD /lib /usr/src/app/lib
ADD env.sh /usr/src/app
ADD package.json /usr/src/app
ADD tux.js /usr/src/app
```

Comment: You can limit the number of layers created by using only one ADD instruction: `ADD env.sh package.json tux.js /usr/src/app`

Answer (score 0):

The error that reads off `undefined` is an indication that you are missing a package. After all if a package is not installed then how can it be defined? This would mean that you did not build the container correctly and I think I see the culprit.

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

*COPY . /usr/src/app*

RUN npm install
```

According [to the dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), the COPY command copies ***files***, not directories which you specified with `COPY . /usr/src/app`. Instead, try replacing `.` with `*` as this will specify ALL files in the current directory that you decide to initiate the `docker build` from.

Comment: no luck. running COPY * /usr/src/app copied every file (not the directory) to my /user/src/app directory. Close (I think), but no luck.

Comment: have you been able to get your app working without using a container? So just building it on your local machine have you been successful? Its not a good idea to try to get incomplete apps into docker containers as that may just add a whole new layer of confusion. I doubt your app is incomplete but it doesn't hurt to know.

Comment: Works great locally. No issues there. It's getting the headless environment setup and running properly -- I'm guessing that I'm missing a dependency of sorts.... just not sure what exactly as the output isn't verbose enough.